# SQL incrementing query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query. All the selects is technically the same, just an incrementing value on the multiplier. I need this upto *64.

Any advice on how to do this in a more efficient way than I am doing now?

```
SELECT 
CONVERT(INT,cast(reverse(substring(char_data, 305+16*1, 2)) as BINARY(2))) AS inventory1,
CONVERT(INT,cast(reverse(substring(char_data, 305+16*2, 2)) as BINARY(2))) AS inventory2,
CONVERT(INT,cast(reverse(substring(char_data, 305+16*3, 2)) as BINARY(2))) AS inventory3,
CONVERT(INT,cast(reverse(substring(char_data, 305+16*4, 2)) as BINARY(2))) AS inventory4,
CONVERT(INT,cast(reverse(substring(char_data, 305+16*5, 2)) as BINARY(2))) AS inventory5,
CONVERT(INT,cast(reverse(substring(char_data, 305+16*6, 2)) as BINARY(2))) AS inventory6,
CONVERT(INT,cast(reverse(substring(char_data, 305+16*7, 2)) as BINARY(2))) AS inventory7,
CONVERT(INT,cast(reverse(substring(char_data, 305+16*8, 2)) as BINARY(2))) AS inventory8,
CONVERT(INT,cast(reverse(substring(char_data, 305+16*9, 2)) as BINARY(2))) AS inventory9,
CONVERT(INT,cast(reverse(substring(char_data, 305+16*10, 2)) as BINARY(2))) AS inventory10
    ..........SO ON TO 64.............
FROM CHAR_DATA0 
WHERE CHAR_KEY=10
```

Thanks alot guys.

--Edit--

I'm using MSSQL

Comment: Why would you do it in a query?! do it in PHP\JAVA\C# what ever you're using, this should not be SQL stuff.

Comment: It looks like you need to break up that CHAR_DATA field into relational fields in a good data model. All that data encoded into one field is just asking for trouble.

Comment: How many rows are returned by your query?  Rather than sixty-four columns and a few rows, could you work with sixty-four rows and a few columns (e.g., [inventoryN], [value]) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do it without dynamic SQL

```
declare @stmt nvarchar(max), @i int

select @i = 1

while @i <= 64
begin
    select
        @stmt = 
            isnull(@stmt + ', ', '') + 
            'convert(int, cast(reverse(substring(char_data, 305+16*' + 
            cast(@i as nvarchar(10)) + ', 2)) as binary(2))) as inventory' + 
            cast(@i as nvarchar(10))

    select @i = @i + 1
end

select @stmt = 'select ' + @stmt + ' FROM CHAR_DATA0 WHERE CHAR_KEY=@CHAR_KEY'

exec dbo.sp_executesql
    @stmt = @stmt,
    @params = N'@CHAR_KEY int',
    @CHAR_KEY = 10
```

Comment: It asked my to wait another minute before accepting. :) sorry. Its accepted now.